# Some properties of the Reynold's operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, finite-groups, linear-transformations, representation-theory

Let consider $V$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, $G$ a finite groupe and the following linear map : $\pi_G : V \rightarrow V, v \mapsto \dfrac{1}{\vert G\vert}\displaystyle\sum\limits_{g \in G}\rho(g)(v)$, where $\rho : G \rightarrow GL(V)$ is a representation of $G$ on $V$. This map is also known as the Reynold's operator.

Let define $V^G=\{v \in V \ / \ \rho(g)(v)=v \ ; \ \forall g\in G \}$ the subspace of invariants vectors go $V$. We have the fact that $\pi_G$ is a linear projector on $V^G$ and $\text{Im}(\pi_G)=V^G$.

Now, we consider a family of Reynold's operators $(\pi_G^{(i)})_{1\le i \le r}$ where for each $i$ : $\pi_G^{(i)} : V \rightarrow V,v \mapsto \dfrac{1}{\vert G\vert}\displaystyle\sum\limits_{g \in G}\rho_i(g)(v)$, with $\rho_i : V \rightarrow GL(V)$ a representation of $G$ on $V$ and we define for each $i$, $V_i^G=\{v \in V \ / \ \rho_i(g)(v)=v \ ; \ \forall g\in G \}$. I think as before we have for each $i$ the fact that $\pi_G^{(i)}$ is a linear projector on $V_i^G$.

If we could write : $V=\bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^r(V_i^G)$, would we have the following properties :

$\bullet$ for all $i\in\{1,...,r\}$, $\pi_G^{(i)}\circ \pi_G^{(i)} =\pi_G^{(i)}$.

$\bullet$ for all $i,j \in \{1,...,r\}$, $\pi_G^{(i)}\circ \pi_G^{(j)}=\pi_G^{(j)}\circ \pi_G^{(i)}= 0$.

$\bullet$ $id_V= \sum \limits_{i=1}^r \pi_G^{(i)}$.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The first dot always holds, you can easily check that $\pi_G$ is idempotent (that's equivalent to being a projection). The third dot would follow from the second one and considering dimensions. However, I guess the second dot needs some additional hypothesis about the representations.